# Applied Schema on JSON kafka topic gives all null fields

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I'm using the hortonworks suite of tools and trying to parse json data that is coming in from a kafka topic into a dataframe. However, when I query the in-memory table, the schema of the dataframe seems to be correct, but all the values are null and I don't really know why.

The json data going into the kafka topic looks as such:

```
{"index":"0","Conrad":"Persevering system-worthy intranet","address":"8905 Robert Prairie\nJoefort, LA 41089","bs":"envisioneer web-enabled mindshare","city":"Davidland","date_time":"1977-06-26 06:12:48","email":"eric56@parker-robinson.com","paragraph":"Kristine Nash","randomdata":"Growth special factor bit only. Thing agent follow moment seat. Nothing agree that up view write include.","state":"1030.0"}
```

The code in my Zeppelin notebook is as such:

```
%dep 
z.load("org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.3.1")

%pyspark

#Defining my schema

from pyspark.sql.types import StructType , StringType , LongType , IntegerType

schema = StructType().add("index", IntegerType()).add("Conrad", StringType()).add("address",StringType()).add("bs",StringType()).add("city",StringType()).add("date_time",LongType()).add("email",StringType()).add("name",StringType()).add("paragraph",StringType()).add("randomdata",IntegerType()).add("state",StringType())

# Read data from kafka topic

lines = spark.readStream.format("kafka").option("kafka.bootstrap.servers","x.x.x.x:2181").option("startingOffsets", "latest").option("subscribe","testdata").load().select(from_json(col("value").cast("string"), schema).alias("parsed_value"))

# Start the stream and query the in-memory table
query=lines.writeStream.format("memory").queryName("t10").start()
raw= spark.sql("select parsed_value.* from t10")
```

I am currently explicitly defining the schema, but my ultimate goal is to get the avro schema from the [Hortonworks Schema Registry](https://hortonworks.com/tutorial/schema-registry-in-trucking-iot-on-hdf/section/3/) . Would be good if someone could show me how to do this as well.

Thanks!

Comment: I am not aware of a Spark processor yet for the Hortonworks Registry.

Comment: NiFi is generally used instead as part of HDF, and can apply an Avro schema

Comment: NiFi is being used to get the data into the kafka topic, now I want to get this data into a pyspark dataframe. The data was originally in csv, I'm using NiFi and Hortonworks Schema registry to apply a schema and convert the data into json format.

Comment: Got it. Well, for the data posted, `"randomdata",IntegerType()` isn't correct, so maybe the JSON parser is failing, and `kafka.bootstrap.servers` wouldn't be connecting to port 2181

Comment: @cricket_007 Similarly `index` is not `Integer`. In cases like this parser will simply fail to parse whole record.